# Ender 5 (not Pro or Plus) extruder motor port not working

Tags: extruder, creality-ender-5, stepper

I have a Creality Ender 5 (with CR Touch installed) and I just decided a few days ago to switch out my default V1.1.4 board with the new Silent Creality V4.2.7 motherboard (to make it silent and let me be able to install the CR Touch). When the package arrived, I immediately put it on my machine and flashed the firmware. Everything was going well until I realised that the extruder motor was going backward. I knew that it was the firmware’s problem based on other people's experiences which matched mine. I tried to do what they did which was switch the wires around. After that, the extruder stopped working.

I tried switching the wire of the extruder with the Z-axis on the mainboard. The extruder spins but the Z-axis stops working.

I concluded that it was the port's problem so I reached out to the manufacturer for a replacement. Even though they sent me the wrong version, the V4.2.2, The extruder port still didn't work.

I noticed when I switched the Z-axis wire to the extruder port and make take the Z-axis wire and plug it into the extruder, the extruder makes a "Thud" sound.

Does anyone know the solution to this? I have been struggling with this for 1 month now. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Did you heat up the hotend? Marlin is normally built with cold extrusion protection so that extruder motion commands are not executed unless the hotend is above a minimal temperature for extrusion.

Comment: I have. I always heat up my extruder to 215 degrees every time I want to test extruder.

Comment: If you unplug and plug stepper cables while the board is powered, you can kill the stepper drivers on the board. Always un-power the board when you replace stepper cables.

Comment: oh, so that's why... I guess i have to wait for the new board to arrive to get it to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have got a new board and I got a new wire as well. I plugged everything in and the extruder stiffened at startup like it was supposed to but when I tried to make it spin, it refused to spin. it felt as if it went forward one step and back again. please help. I think it might be a software issue.